Correct notation for chaining congruences (and equalities)
I am writng some material about congruences. I'm wondering if it is correct to write it like this:
\begin{align*}
2^{30}&\equiv 2^{6}(\operatorname{mod}13)= 2^{4}\cdot 2^{2}(\operatorname{mod}13) \equiv
16\cdot 4\,(\operatorname{mod}13)\\
&\equiv 3\cdot 4(\operatorname{mod}13)= 12 \,(\operatorname{mod}13)\equiv (-1)\,(\operatorname{mod}13)
\end{align*}
Primarily, I'm thinking if it is ok to write signs = and $\equiv $ in the same line and am I writing  $(\operatorname{mod}13) $  too many times? Should I write it only once at the end of calculus? I have seen so many ways of writing it and I am not sure what is the best. Thank you all.

A suggestion: add the [tag:notation] tag to your tags.

Just once, at the end. Mixing $=$ and $\equiv$ looks ugly to me.

You should never repeat those mods as you do above. Doing so seems to imply that you are mistakenly thinking of those mods as (remainder) operations, instead of a (congruence) relations (see here for elaboration on this common confusion). $\ \ $

Chaining (equivalence) relations (here congruences) is standard notation - as explained in the dupe. See also this question on chaining congruences.

Indeed, I also would prefer that $=$ and $\equiv$ are not mixed here. Also, it is enough to write modulo $13$ at the end:
$$
2^{30} \equiv 2^{6}\equiv 2^{4}\cdot 2^{2}\equiv
16\cdot 4\equiv 3\cdot 4 \equiv -1 \pmod{13}
$$
Here we have used $2^{12}\equiv 1\pmod{13}$, by Little Fermat.

The bmod above is incorrect and pedagogically misleading (it promotes the common  confusion between mod operations vs. relations). Also "should not" is too strong, since sometimes using an equality can convey useful info about the implicit reasoning employed

@BillDubuque I see. I replaced it by pmod.

Please strive not to post more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs. This is enforced site policy, see here.
